# d3.js label inside path deformed

Tags: d3.js, path, label

i added a label inside a path successfully but when i try to center this label by changing manually x and dy attributes. the label deforms in the center.
here is some picture and its corresponding code.
before changing the x attributes its value 135:

[image]

```
<svg width="1306" height="628">
<g>
<path name="cf40" d="M590.3383838385344,295.20151514932513L756.3916666656733,317.13308080658317L878.5818181820214,279.5361111164093L822.186363636516,527.0494949556887L728.1939393933862,555.2472222223878Z" id="polygon2" style="fill: steelblue;"></path>
</g>
<text x="135" dy="105"><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#polygon2">CF40</textPath></text>
</svg>
```

after changing the x attributes new value is 145:

[image]

```
<svg width="1306" height="628">
<g>
<path name="cf40" d="M590.3383838385344,295.20151514932513L756.3916666656733,317.13308080658317L878.5818181820214,279.5361111164093L822.186363636516,527.0494949556887L728.1939393933862,555.2472222223878Z" id="polygon2" style="fill: steelblue;"></path>
</g>
<text x="145" dy="105"><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#polygon2">CF40</textPath></text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing "deformed" here. That's the expected behaviour: you're using a `textPath` to position the text, and the path you're referencing changes orientation at the first L command.

You can clearly see that there is nothing wrong when we draw some (red) lines, showing this "bend":

```html
<svg width="400" height="300">
<g>
<path name="cf40" d="M590.3383838385344,295.20151514932513L756.3916666656733,317.13308080658317L878.5818181820214,279.5361111164093L822.186363636516,527.0494949556887L728.1939393933862,555.2472222223878Z" id="polygon2" style="fill: steelblue;" transform="translate(-500,-260)"></path>
</g>
<text x="145" dy="105"><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#polygon2">CF40</textPath></text>
<line x1="756.3916666656733" y1="317.133080" x2="728.1939393933862"
 y2="555.2472222223878" stroke="red" transform="translate(-500,-260)"
></line>
<line x1="756.3916666656733" y1="317.133080" x2="822.186363636516"
 y2="527.049" stroke="red" transform="translate(-500,-260)"
></line>
</svg>
```

And you can see that even better if we create *several* texts, increasing the `dy` up to your value (105):

```html
<svg width="400" height="300">
<g>
<path name="cf40" d="M590.3383838385344,295.20151514932513L756.3916666656733,317.13308080658317L878.5818181820214,279.5361111164093L822.186363636516,527.0494949556887L728.1939393933862,555.2472222223878Z" id="polygon2" style="fill: steelblue;" transform="translate(-500,-260)"></path>
</g>
<text x="145" dy="15"><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#polygon2">CF40</textPath></text>
<text x="145" dy="40"><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#polygon2">CF40</textPath></text>
<text x="145" dy="60"><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#polygon2">CF40</textPath></text>
<text x="145" dy="80"><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#polygon2">CF40</textPath></text>
<text x="145" dy="105"><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#polygon2">CF40</textPath></text>
<line x1="756.3916666656733" y1="317.133080" x2="728.1939393933862"
 y2="555.2472222223878" stroke="red" transform="translate(-500,-260)"
></line>
<line x1="756.3916666656733" y1="317.133080" x2="822.186363636516"
 y2="527.049" stroke="red" transform="translate(-500,-260)"
></line>
</svg>
```

Possible solution: alternatively, you can draw a curve. That way, the text will follow the path without breaks:

```html
<svg width="400" height="300">
<g>
<path name="cf40" d="M590.3383838385344,295.20151514932513 C 756 327,756 327, 878.5818181820214,279.5361111164093L822.186363636516,527.0494949556887L728.1939393933862,555.2472222223878Z" id="polygon2" style="fill: steelblue;" transform="translate(-500,-260)"></path>
</g>
<text x="145" dy="105"><textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#polygon2">CF40</textPath></text>
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks man i 100% understood, i have a one question how i can center this text without using the BBOX methods , cause this method does not works in banana shapes.

Comment: @SaidMarar if you ask this question in the comment, I am the only one that's gonna read it. But if you post it as *another* question, everybody is gonna read it.